# How to add JavaScript or CSS library to Composer project?

Tags: javascript, 8, theming, composer

For some cases, there is the need to add a JavaScript or CSS package to a project. One of those cases was the [DropzoneJS package](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropzonejs) for the [`drupal/entity_browser`](https://packagist.drupal-composer.org/packages/drupal/entity_browser). All recommendations I could read online read like

> 1. Download *manually*
> 2. Install *manually*

or like

> Use Drush

This is not really satisfying as there should be a way without user interaction or working around interaction in setup scripts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The library can be installed into a custom path by utilizing [`extra : installer-paths`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) to for e.g.:

```
web/sites/libraries/{$name}
```

Additional to that, we define the required [package repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) with the needed `type` of `drupal-library`. Example `composer.json` for a project:

```
{
    "name"              : "example-composer/example-project",
    "description"       : "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type"              : "project",
    "minimum-stability" : "dev",
    "prefer-stable"     : true,
    "scripts"           : {
        "post-install-cmd" : "sh ./scripts/composer/post-install.sh"
    },
    "require"           : {
        "composer/installers"       : "^1.0.20",
        "drupal/entity_browser"     : "8.1.0-alpha1",
        "cweagans/composer-patches" : "~1.0",
        "drupal/core"               : "8.0.*",
        "drush/drush"               : "~8.0",
        "drupal/console"            : "~0.9",
        "drupal/devel"              : "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drupal/entity_browser"     : "8.1.0-alpha1",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form" : "8.1.0-alpha2",
        "drupal/dropzonejs"         : "8.1.*@dev",
        "enyo/dropzone"             : "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories"      : [
        {
            "type" : "composer",
            "url"  : "https://packagist.drupal-composer.org"
        },
        {
            "type"    : "package",
            "package" : {
                "name"    : "enyo/dropzone",
                "version" : "dev-master",
                "type"    : "drupal-library",
                "dist"    : {
                    "url"  : "https://github.com/enyo/dropzone.git",
                    "type" : "drupal-library"
                },
                "source"  : {
                    "url"       : "https://github.com/enyo/dropzone.git",
                    "type"      : "git",
                    "reference" : "origin/master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "extra"             : {
        "installer-paths" : {
            "web/core"                    : [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            ...
            "web/sites/libraries/{$name}" : [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The `dist` part can be left off and is only needed for `--prefer-dist` cases when installing via `php composer.phar update --prefer-dist` (opposite: `--prefer-source`). To install a **version** and not the latest from the `master` branch, you need to set the version directly at the package to require then from there. Example:

```
"require" : {
    "enyo/dropzone" : "v4.2.*@dev"
},
"repositories" : [
    {
        "type"    : "package",
        "package" : {
            "name"    : "enyo/dropzone",
            "version" : "v4.2.0",
            "type"    : "drupal-library",
            "source"  : {
                "url"       : "https://github.com/enyo/dropzone.git",
                "type"      : "git",
                "reference" : "origin/master"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: For this type of libraries I prefer bower.

Comment: @Ivan Jaros, I agree with you. Composer is for **PHP** libraries.

Comment: Package Managers are for _packages_ and are not restricted by language. Also, what would you do if you have **no Nodejs** available in your install location?

Comment: @kaiser In this case no...Composer is, literally, billed as: Dependency Manager **for PHP**. Emphasis mine. Front end packages should be handled by a front end package manner, Bower is a good example though it has its problems. You can shoehorn a CSS dependency into Composer, just like you could do the same to an NPM package, doesn't mean you _should_. If nodejs isn't available, and it's required to do a proper job, it should be installed. Not being able to find a hammer is not an excuse to use a screwdriver to do a hammer's job, in my opinion

Comment: @Clive You are taking that Composer quote quite literally. You wouldn't take Bowers quote of "A package manager for the web" to justify that you are fetching PHP packages with it, right? Aside from that, I would not want two different package managers - who know nothing of each other - to install into the same directory.

Comment: @kaiser Sorry, never going to agree with you here. This is from Bower's front page: _Bower can manage components that contain HTML, CSS, JavaScript, fonts or even image files. Bower doesn’t concatenate or minify code or do anything else - it just installs the right versions of the packages you need and their dependencies._. If you can find a similar quote anywhere on the web that says Composer is supposed to be used for the same thing, let's see it :)

Comment: @Clive Please take your time and rephrase this into an answer (and please clean up our last comments that are just opinionated). The more possibilities for later readers, the better. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @kaiser Just heading to the dentist (groan) will do it a bit later tonight :)

Comment: @Clive "Bower is a good example though it has its problems" - anything in particular?

Comment: @IvanJaros Because it does _not_ solve conflicts (multiple packages installing the same dependencies multiple times). Also you need packages that have a `bower.json` to not install stuff that the original dev only needed to develop the package or build the distributable files. Upside: It serves _very small_ packages if well configured.

Comment: What Kaiser said @Ivan. Great for small, insular projects; doesn't necessarily scale well to larger projects with more entry points, unless you're careful/lucky in my experience

Comment: An interesting discussion, but the only practical among you is @kaiser who came with an answer. The others are apparently not convinced enough to come with an actual example how to do the same with Bower. People like me, looking for a answer, will go with an answer, not with some unpractical opinionated discussion.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer, "don't use composer".

We've had pretty good success using a root npm package called "copy-files-from-to"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-files-from-to

Example `package.json`

```
{
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "copy-files-from-to"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "blazy": "^1.8.2",
    "copy-files-from-to": "^2.3.0",
    "select2": "github:select2/select2"
  },
  "copyFiles": [
    {
      "from": "node_modules/blazy/*.js",
      "to": "public/libraries/blazy/"
    },    
    {
      "from": "node_modules/select2/dist/**",
      "to": "public/libraries/select2/dist/"
    }
  ]
}
```